# How to get a "backtrace" (like gdb) using only ptrace (linux, x86/x86_64)

Tags: linux, gdb, x86, x86-64, ptrace

I want to get a `backtrace`-like output as gdb does. But I want to do this via `ptrace()` directly. My platform is Linux, x86; and, later x86_64.

Now I want only to read return addresses from the stack, without conversion into symbol names.

So, for test program, compiled in `-O0` mode by `gcc-4.5`:

```
  int g() {
    kill(getpid(),SIGALRM);
  }
  int f() {
    int a;
    int b;
    a = g();
    b = a;
    return a+b;
  }
  int e() {
    int c;
    c = f();
  }
  main() {
    return e();
  }
```

I will start a my program and connect with `ptrace` to test program at very beginning. Then, I will do PTRACE_CONT and will wait for signal. When test program will do a self-kill; the signal will be delivered to my program. At this moment I want to read return addresses, they will be like (because `kill` function is active at the moment):

```
 0x00_some_address_in_g
 0x00_some_address_in_f
 0x00_some_address_in_e
 0x00_some_address_in_main
 0x00_some_address_in__libc_start_main
```

How can I find return addresses of currently stopped test process with `ptrace`? There will be a loop over frames? When should I stop such loop?

PS: yes, this is also very like [`backtrace(3)` libc function](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) in idea, but I want to do this externally via ptrace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example posted by osgx will work only with code that uses frame pointers. `x86_64` code produced by GCC with optimizations doesn't. The kernel `vdso` code on `x86` doesn't use frame pointers on at least some processors. GCC 4.6 (with optimization) doesn't use frame pointers in `x86` mode either.

All of the above combine to make the "stack crawl via frame pointers" exceedingly unreliable.

You can use `libunwind` (which supports both [local](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/man/unw_init_local%283%29.html) (in-process) and [global](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/man/unw_init_remote%283%29.html) (out-of-process via ptrace) unwinding).

Or you'll have to re-implement very large portion of `libunwind`.

[Example](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libunwind.git/plain/tests/test-ptrace.c?h=v1.0-stable) of getting backtrace via `ptrace` using `libunwind`.

Comment: can you provide link to libunwind external unwinding documents?

Comment: This? http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/man/libunwind-ptrace(3).html - Is there some examples of getting backtrace with libunwind-ptrace?

Comment: I've added links to documentation. No: libunwind-ptrace is not what you want -- it's the part of libunwind that implements ptrace facilities. You can use that part to re-implement higher levels of libunwind, but there should be no reason for you to do so.

Comment: If I'm reading the documentation correctly, to use the ptrace code, one should create an addr space using `_UPT_accessors`, and pass that to `unw_init_remote`

Comment: Can't use libunwind for sparc "`Unknown ELF target`"; the test-ptrace fails on my x86 with "`too deeply nested---assuming bogus unwind`"

Comment: Your question was about about "linux(x86/x86_64)". Last I checked, SPARC was not an x86 variant. Unwinding on SPARC is actually trivial, and doesn't require anything nearly as complicated as libunwind. As for test-ptrace, it (and several others) are known to fail. Check libunwind mailing list for current known failures.

Answer (score 0):

May be, source of `pstack(1)` utility will help me: (online git from [debian](http://packages.debian.org/source/sid/pstack)). Unfortunately this is x86 32-bit only

http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=collab-maint/pstack.git;a=blob;f=pstack.c;h=61beb8d10fa490492ab351115f261614d00adb6d;hb=HEAD#l547

```
 547 static int crawl(int pid)
 548 {
 549   unsigned long pc, fp, nextfp, nargs, i, arg;
 550   int error_occured = 0;
 551 
 552   errno = 0;
 553   fp = -1;
 554 
 555   pc = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, EIP * 4, 0);
 556   if (pc != -1 || !errno)
 557     fp = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, EBP * 4, 0);
 558 
 559   if ((pc != -1 && fp != -1) || !errno) {
 560     print_pc(pc);
 561     for ( ; !errno && fp; ) {
 562       nextfp = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, fp, 0);
 563       if (nextfp == (unsigned) -1 && errno) break;
 564 
 565       nargs = (nextfp - fp - 8) / 4;
 566       if (nargs > MAXARGS) nargs = MAXARGS;
 567       if (nargs > 0) {
 568         fputs(" (", stdout);
 569         for (i = 1; i <= nargs; i++) {
 570           arg = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, fp + 4 * (i + 1), 0);
 571           if (arg == (unsigned) -1 && errno) break;
 572           printf("%lx", arg);
 573           if (i < nargs) fputs(", ", stdout);
 574         }
 575         fputc(')', stdout);
 576         nargs = nextfp - fp - 8 - (4 * nargs);
 577         if (!errno && nargs > 0) printf(" + %lx\n", nargs);
 578         else fputc('\n', stdout);
 579       } else fputc('\n', stdout);
 580 
 581       if (errno || !nextfp) break;
 582       pc = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, fp + 4, 0);
 583       if (pc == (unsigned) -1 && errno) break;
 584       fp = nextfp;
 585       print_pc(pc);
 586     }
 587     if (fp) error_occured = 1;
 588   } else error_occured = 1;
 589 
 590   if (error_occured) perror("crawl");
 591   else errno = 0;
 592   return errno;
 593 }
 594
```

Also, quick test says that is it not very reliable, but sometimes it can print something.