# Can libunwind-ptrace attach to crashing process?

Tags: c++, debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, stack-trace

I'd like to collect just the stacktrace for crashes which would normally result in very large coredumps. It seems like one option is to attach to the process when it's in a crashed but not yet cleaned up state. I tried gstack which uses gdb but gdb didn't like the fact that the process had already crashed.

Does anyone know if libunwind could do this?

This question seemed relevant:

[How to get a "backtrace" (like gdb) using only ptrace (linux, x86/x86_64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258273/how-to-get-a-backtrace-like-gdb-using-only-ptrace-linux-x86-x86-64/7259299#7259299)

and contained a reference to this example:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libunwind.git/plain/tests/test-ptrace.c?h=v1.0-stable

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: On a project where I work `pstack` (on Linux it is `gstack`) is run from a signal handler like a SIGSEGV handler. That is in the signal handler first `fork()` is done, then `execl()` and then `wait()`. All these function are async signal safe. Stacktraces are collected and saved without any problems.

Comment: On Linux check out the "coredump filter" instead.  This is how ABRT works.  FWIW gdb doesn't care about the state of your process.  If you couldn't get a stack trace, then most likely the stack was trashed.